# JS: preserve top level keys when sorting nested array with _orderBy()

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

i am trying to sort and array with [_orderBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy) and it has the unfortunate by-product of blowing away the top level array keys!  i need to be able to sort by those top level keys as well as sub keys (which it does just fine).

```js
bigArray = {
  "22H7564": {  //  <------  these are the top level keys
    "name":"Thor",
    "age:"600",
    "height":187,
  },
  "20H3211": {
    "name":"Mesa",
    "age:"42",
    "height":120,
  },
  "27H4506": {
    "name":"Jesper",
    "age:"122",
    "height":143,
  },
}
```

this is the sorted-but-borked results (`_orderBy(BigArray, 'name', 'desc')`):

```js
bigArray = {
  "0": {  //  <------  FRAAACK!  i need these!
    "name":"Jesper",
    "age:"122",
    "height":143,
  },
  "1": {
    "name":"Mesa",
    "age:"42",
    "height":120,
  },
  "2": {
    "name":"Thor",
    "age:"600",
    "height":187,
  },
}
```

is there a way to sort AND preserve these top level keys?  i need to be able to sort those as well.

Comment: sub keys? you mean nested keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a ton of research sparked by @Paul's illuminating example, i finally stumbled on this solution, courtesy of **not** the article, but [the *comment* by Max Loh](https://medium.com/p/94b030a1604c/responses/show) at the very bottom of [this blog post](https://medium.com/chrisburgin/javascript-converting-an-object-to-an-array-94b030a1604c).  here's the solution to this problem and it works beautifully.  just had to adjust two things in the downstream code. anyway.

```js
let newArray= Object.entries(bigArray).map(e => ({ id: e[0], data: e[1] }))
```

this effectively transmuted my object into an array that i was able to easily sort with `_.orderBy`.  aaand i learned a deeper level of JS to boot.  win-win.  :)

hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `bigArray` is actually an object and no array. Define it as an array `[]` and you get the results you need.

```js
bigArray = [{
  "22H7564": {  //  <------  these are the top level keys
    "name":"Thor",
    "age":"600",
    "height":187,
  },
  "20H3211": {
    "name":"Mesa",
    "age":"42",
    "height":120,
  },
  "27H4506": {
    "name":"Jesper",
    "age":"122",
    "height":143,
  },
}]

console.log(_.orderBy(bigArray, 'name', 'desc'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: :facepalm:  of course.  dammit.  i always confuse the two when i bounce back and forth with PHP. :(  thank you.

Comment: okay.  i check the results of the axios query that returns the data and it **does** dump into the previously declared object: `bigArray = [];`. so what's happening that the object is now an array?  and forgive me if this is a dumb question, i've just never come across this situation before.  :P  and what's the best method to get it back into an array?

Comment: so i've been tinkering with this all day and, yeah... while this is technically useful information, i can't do anything with it.  the axios data is JSON encoded as an object and i am struggling trying to convert it into an array of object to no effect.  so while technically this points out the *reason*, it doesn't offer a *solution*.

Comment: I just noticed that my result isn't even correct. It's not sorting at all. Nevertheless: I'm happy you found a solution to your problem. :)

Comment: Heh! No worries! You got me pointed in the right direction. That's worth as much as an answer to me. 